# How Do I get Only Sum of Values in Same Day mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mySQL table like this with table name `transaction`:

```
ID  |   date    |   amount  |   type    |   balance
----------------------------------------------------
1   |   day1    |   100     |   dr      |   100
2   |   day1    |   5       |   dr      |   105
3   |   day2    |   100     |   dr      |   205
4   |   day2    |   20      |   cr      |   185
5   |   day3    |   5       |   cr      |   180

.. and so on
```

I can get transactions using SQL query. That is no problem for me. But what I want is SQL query for

1. Get data by Day (last 30 days)
2. If there is multiple entry for debit (dr) in same day. It sum up.
3. If there is multiple entry for credit (cr) in same day. It sum up.
4. Day end balance ( all balance are calculated everytime debit or credit is done). So very last entry of the day is the end balance of the day.

**Edit:** Added a no 4. Forgot to add it before. I also need a day end balance.

**For example**

1. For Day1 : `Dr 105`, `Cr 0` and `balance 105`
2. For Day2 : `Dr 100`, `Cr 20` and `balance 185`

FYI: Date column is `timestamp`.

Comment: I think you may need to add a desired result for the change in the question. What would for example be the desired result if there were no credit for a day?

Comment: If not debit or credit for a day there will not be an entry and balance is not changed.

Comment: So in your example you'd want what? Just 180 for day1, 185 for day2?

Comment: There was a typo on the table the last one is `day3`. Fixed it with a example.

Comment: Updated my answer below to reflect your example.

Answer (score 5):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT DATE(date), type, SUM(amount)
FROM transaction
GROUP BY DATE(date), type
```

working [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37801/3)

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: You added some requirements to your question to get only the last balance per day, so updated the query. Since MySQL is missing ranking functions, you'll as far as I know need to do it using a dependent subquery;

```
SELECT 
  DATE(date) date, 
  SUM(IF(type='dr',amount,0)) dr, 
  SUM(IF(type='cr',amount,0)) cr,
  (SELECT balance FROM transaction t2 WHERE t2.date=MAX(t.date)) balance
FROM transaction t
GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

...or a `JOIN`...

```
SELECT 
  DATE(t.date) date, 
  SUM(IF(t.type='dr',t.amount,0)) dr, 
  SUM(IF(t.type='cr',t.amount,0)) cr, 
  t2.balance
FROM transaction t
JOIN transaction t2
  ON DATE(t.date)=DATE(t2.date)
 AND t2.date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM transaction GROUP BY DATE(date))
GROUP BY DATE(t.date);
```

Which is more efficient you'll have to test on your data, but especially the `GROUP BY DATE(date)` may cause some trouble so you may want to add an actual date column to the table that you can group by.

If the `id` is what you want to use as your detection of the last credit/debit of the day instead of `date`, the queries should be fairly straight forward to update.

[An SQLfiddle to test both](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb75f/1).

Comment: Looks complicated :) I will add an update when I give it a go.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(IF(type='dr',amount,0)) Dr,
    SUM(IF(type='cr',amount,0)) Dr,
    balance as Balance
FROM transaction
WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: As for the balance, I do not need the `SUM()`. See the balance gets updated everytime debit or credit entry are made. What I need for balance is `day end value` (balance from newest entry for the day).

Answer (score 1):

Also if you need two columns `Dr` and `Cr` in the query then:

```
SELECT DATE(date), 
SUM(CASE WHEN type='dr' THEN amount ELSE 0 END ) as DR,
SUM(CASE WHEN type='cr' THEN amount ELSE 0 END ) as CR

FROM transaction
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY DATE(date)
```

Comment: The latter name should probably be `CR`, not `DR`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a mysql question, you can abbreviate the query:

```
SELECT
    DATE(date) DATE
    SUM((type='dr') * amount) as DR,
    SUM((type='cr') * amount) as CR
FROM transaction
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY DATE(date)
```

Notice that I don't use a CASE or an IF etc, i just multiply the boolean test result by the amount, because in mysql, true is 1 and false is 0!